# Is there any way by which we can store Images in an array to a SQL database in python?

Tags: python

I wanted to store the images that gets appended in a array to a sql database.

```
img=cv2.imread(r'C:\\Users\ADMIN\\Documents\\IMG_20161231_133557.jpg')
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
imgArr=cropFaces(img)
imgt=imgArr[0].tobytes()
insertFaceIntoDB(1,'John',imgt)
```

The image should be stored in my database.

Comment: generally this is discouraged, see for e.g: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/150669

Comment: Thanks I stored embeddings obtained using facenet instead.